# Why does converting VB Code to C# give me an error?

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with converting the below lines of code to `C#`.

```
//VB Code:
Dim Query As String = "UPDATE Lidhja_Sh_A_M SET Id_A=@Id_A, Id_Sh=@Id_Sh,  Id_M=@Id_M WHERE Id_L=@Id_L"
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Query, con)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_A", Trim(Me.txbIDLA.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Sh", Trim(Me.txbIDLSh.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_M", Trim(Me.txbIDLM.Text))
```

```
// C# code with error
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_A", Strings.Trim(this.txbIDLA.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Sh", Strings.Trim(this.txbIDLSh.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_M", Strings.Trim(this.txbIDLM.Text));
```

Where is the problem in the `C#` code?

Comment: I wonder why developerfusion's converter suggests `Strings.Trim` if such thing does not exist in C#. +1 for the question.

Comment: @Neolisk - Trim is just a method and it perfectly usable in C#.  If the method were called Foo, would you expect the converter to just omit it?  How can it know?  The safer course is to convert what it can and assume that the proper assemblies are referenced.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: When I tried `Strings.Trim` in a brand new C# project, it did not work. Am I doing anything wrong? Just putting `var a = Strings.Trim("123");` and it says `The name 'Strings' does not exist in the current context`. I tried `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;`, but it did not help. My assumption was that code converters should produce code that's perfectly valid as far as compiler is concerned. If it cannot, it should display a warning.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: My apologies, I forgot to reference Microsoft.VisualBasic, now it's working. Well, I would still expect the converter to notify me about required dependencies.

Comment: @Neolisk - I guess the converter is not that smart.  Perhaps it assumes that all the required assemblies are referenced.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `Trim` method like that in c#. You have to call it on `string` instance instead, e.g.:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_A", this.txbIDLA.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fjalet_Sh", Trim(Me.txbFjalaSh.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Sh",Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem(0).ToString)   // how to convert to c sharp this line  please

Comment: +1 but you should be using "".Trim() in vb.net too. Strings.Trim() is a holdover from VB.

Comment: Strings.Trim is perfectly usable in C#, but I agree that using the string.Trim method is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_A", txbIDLA.Text.Trim());

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Sh", txbIDLSh.Text.Trim());

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_M", txbIDLM.Text.Trim());

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Trim function directly as that is not available in  c sharp. you need to use Trim() function of  String class. Following is the example of doing that

```
string test = " this is the string ";
string trimmedstring = test.Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id_A", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txbIDLA.Text.Trim();
```

Pay attention to the SqlDbType type. It must be same at the Table.